# Передать дату из базы данных LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq

Как получить полную дату записи из базы данных с помощью LINQ.

LINQ запрос

```
IEnumerable<AllOrderView> select = (from order in db.RetailOrders
                                                join status in db.RetailStatus on order.StatusId equals status.Id
                                                join customer in db.RetailCustomers on order.RetailCustomerId equals customer.Id
                                                select new AllOrderView
                                                {
                                                    Id = order.Id,
                                                    FirstName = customer.FirstName,
                                                    LastName = customer.LastName,
                                                    Phone = customer.Phone,
                                                    StatusName = status.StatusName,
                                                    Sum = (int)order.Sum,
                                                    DateTimes = order.Data,
                                                    Comment = order.Comment
                                               }).ToList();
```

В `datagridview` все заполняется кроме даты.

Если пытаться вывести через `string`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если через `DateTime`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если обращаться к `Date`, то вылетает ошибка "Указанный член Date не поддерживается в выражениях LINQ to Entities"

Comment: Интуитивно я догадываюсь, что дата это свойство Data в классе RetailOrder. Поправьте меня, если не так. Если я угадал, то по предоставленной информации невозможно судить о причине проблемы. Если допустить что свойство Data корректно замаплено на соответствующую колонку в таблице, что в этой колонке есть данные, и что тип даных совпадает с типом свойства, то нету никаких предпосылок чтобы приведенный код не заполнял соответствующую колонку в DataGridView. Если все вышеперечисленное верно, убедитесь используя отладчик что соответствующее свойство заполняется в классе AllOrderView.

Comment: Посмотрите так же какой SQL запрос выполняется вызовом метода ToList. Попробуйте выполнить тот же самый SQL запрос вручную и посмотрите результат. Все это позволит сузить круг поиска ошибки.

Comment: @Uranus, Вывел. Проблема была в том, что грид был привязан к источнику данных. Отвязал грид и все стало отображаться.